# In Team Explorer in Visual Studio, can you show stash history?

Tags: visual-studio, git-stash, team-explorer

When using the Team Explorer section of Visual Studio, is there a way to see a stash history? For instance, say someone had stashed changes and then when done had popped the changes. Is there a way to show those stashing and popping changes in the View History option? Or possibly if someone new to stashing didn't pop the stash and only did an apply to the stash, then a month or so later they saw the stash showing in the Stashes drop down and couldn't remember if they had applied the stash or not. Could they see a history entry that shows that they applied "xxxx" stash a month ago?

Or is the only option to view these changes in a history to use the Git Bash Terminal for their stash and pop/apply commands so that they will show up in a `git reflog` command?